# Salesforce Soap API, query not returning the value for boolean fields

Tags: php, api, boolean, salesforce

I have a salesforce query that works without an error. I can use all the data except the boolean fields. I would like to display different information depending on the value (True or False) of the cfl_No_Advance_Sales__c field. If I try to just display the value of the field I get nothing. Here's the code:

---

```
    $query = "Select Id, Name, IsDeleted, LastActivityDate, cfl_Door_Price__c, cfl_Advance_Ticket__c, cfl_Start_Time__c, cfl_Event_Date__c, cfl_BPT_Event_ID__c, cfl_Location__c, cfl_Event_Status__c, LastModifiedDate, cfl_No_Advance_Sales__c, cfl_Total_Advance_Tickets__c FROM cfl_Caffe_Events__c where cfl_Event_Date__c >= ".$tday." and IsDeleted = FALSE and (cfl_Event_Status__c != 'Cancelled') order by cfl_Event_Date__c asc LIMIT 5 ";


$response = $mySforceConnection->query($query);
// QueryResult object is only for PARTNER client
$queryResult = new QueryResult($response);
foreach ($queryResult->records as $record) {

//lots more code in here that works just fine

echo " $".$record->cfl_Door_Price__c." door</div>";
  //check if no advanced sales
print '<br> No Advanced ticket sales value is:'.$record->cfl_No_Advance_Sales__c;

  if ($record->cfl_No_Advance_Sales__c != "False") {
  echo "<div class='etickets'><a href='/events-calendar/event-detail/?id=".$record->Id."'>TICKETS</a></div>"; 
  }else{
       echo "<div class='etickets'>NO ADVANCED TICKETS</div>";
  }
}
```

---

**This is how it prints out...**

$3 door

No Advanced ticket sales value is:
TICKETS

---

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Send `$record->cfl_No_Advance_Sales__c` to `echo`. And also `gettype($record->cfl_No_Advance_Sales__c)`. I suspect that you should compare with normal boolean `false`, not with a string.